# How to access a routes model in Ember 2

Tags: ember.js, ember.js-2

I am having some trouble accessing my route's model inside my template. My model is created successfully as part of an action defined in my home controller:

```
actions: {
    createProject: function () {
        var project = this.store.createRecord('project', {
            name: 'Sample name'
        });
        var self = this;
        var promise = project.save();

        promise.then(function (response) {
            self.transitionToRoute('estimate', project);
        });
        promise.catch(function (errors) {
            console.log(errors);
        });
    }
}
```

The model's uuid is correctly serialized into the URL, with the URL inside my router.js being as follows:

```
  this.route('estimate');
  this.route('estimate', { path: '/estimate/:project_id' });
```

My `estimate` controller also correctly specifies the project dependency:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['project']
});
```

...and I define the model inside my routes/estimate.js as follows:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import AuthenticatedRouteMixin from 'ember-simple-auth/mixins/authenticated-route-mixin';

export default Ember.Route.extend(AuthenticatedRouteMixin, {
    // model: function(params) {
    //     return this.store.find('project', params.project_id);
    // },
    model(params) {
        return this.store.findRecord('project', params.project_id);
    }
});
```

Logging the output of `this.store.findRecord('project', params.project_id)` I get:

```
Class {__ember1458995391969: null, __ember_meta__: Meta}
__ember1458995391969
...
```

However when I try to access the project model inside my estimate handlebars template (using `{{model.project.name}}`), I get nothing (no errors, no output).

Anybody have any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of the model hook is bound to the `model` property of the controller, which binds into the template under the same name.

You should write `{{model.name}}`, not `{{model.project.name}}`.

#### Background

Your model hook is returning an Ember Data promise object directly (which is normal). This means that `model` refers to your project object; there is no `model.project` property.

Rendering `{{model.project.name}}` is like calling `this.get('model.project.name')` in your controller. Ember will return `undefined` for this path, even if `model.project` is `undefined` itself:

```
> $E.get('model')
< Class {store: Class, isLoaded: true, manager: Class, isUpdating: false, __ember1459002119210: "ember610"…}
> $E.get('model.project')
< undefined
> $E.get('model.project.name')
< undefined
> $E.get('model.project.name.whatever')
< undefined
```

So there's no error in this case. And nothing shows up in the template, because `null` and `undefined` are rendered as blank strings.